# Change Steam account email address, having lost access

Tags: steam

How do you change an unverified Steam email address, with no access to the cell phone number and email address for the Steam account?

Comment: Kaw may be trying to access an account of a person that doesn't belong to him. Therefore, answering this question may result in Kaw being able to do so.

Comment: @Diecie I do so hope that if it *is* another person's, that other person doesn't *belong* to them ;) irregardless, I think we can still at least give enough benefit of the doubt to say "contact support".

Answer (score 2):

You can submit a request directly to Steam customer support; if you are unable to convince them that this is your account, and not somebody else's, there is nothing else you can do.

---

To retrieve a lost Steam account without access to the associated phone number or email addresses, follow these steps:

1. Go to ["Steam Support - I forgot my Steam Account name or password"](https://help.steampowered.com/en/wizard/HelpWithLoginInfo?issueid=406).
2. Enter the email address corresponding to the lost Steam account, confirm that you are not a robot and hit *"Search"*.
3. Select *"I no longer have access to this phone number"*.
4. Select *"I no longer have access to this email address"*
5. Fill out the following form to the best of your ability. Make sure you provide an email address that you currently have access to, as support will be using this email to contact you.
6. Confirm that you are not a robot and hit *"Send"*.

Steam support will review your request and get back to you. Ultimately, they will decide whether they have enough evidence to support giving you access to the account. Unfortunately, they need to look at these requests very carefully. What if someone else was trying to use information they knew about you to break in to your Steam account? If your request is denied, there isn't anything else that you can do.

---

[image]

[image]